# Websphere 6.1 server

Tags: websphere

I have an issue in loading jars in websphere server. Some of the jars are present in WEB-INF/lib and some are present in local hard drive(ex., c:\lib folder). How can i load all these jars, during the startup of the application. If WEB-INF jars are loaded, external jars are not getting loading and viceversa..Need help on this....

Answer (score 4):

WebSphere has a hierarchy of classloaders, parent  classloaders cannot see child classloaders, hence you get surprises when you put different aspects of your application in different places.

Never attempt to place application jars in WebSphere's own lib directory, and never adjust WebSphere's own class path. There is ana rchitected way to make external jars visible, I'll explain that in a moment.

There are three places that you can put JAR files so that they will be loaded. By far the the best is simply to place the JARs in WEB-INF/lib. You can specify the search order preference PARENT LAST so that these take prececdence over jars supplied by websphere - but note that some fundamental jars cannot be over-ridden You cannot replace the IBM security for example.

Second you can add jars to the root of the EAR file. Noe that the hierarchy comes into play now, WEB-INF/lib jars can see EAR jars but EAR jars cannot see WEB-INF/lib jars.

Finally you can specify a WebSphere "Shared Libarary".  See the Info Centre for how, it's very easy through the console. A shared library has a classpath, you add jars to that. Then you allocate the shared libarary to individual applicaitons or whole servers.

Once again You WEB app can see the shared library, but i don't beleive taht the convers is true. Hence putting framework code in a shread library may not work for you.

Comment: "is there no other way to make the web-inf/lib jars and other external jars to be made visible at the same time?" - The methods I describe are the "standard" WAS ways of doing things, I know of no useful alternatives. Be vary wary of hacking around this.